# Bitlocker Repair Tool for windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, windows, encryption, bitlocker

I have just enabled bitlocker using a flash drive without TPM on windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.
Just to be prepared - is there any way I can recover data from an encrypted volume in Windows 7 ultimate.

I found links for BitLocker Repair Tool to help recover data from an encrypted volume for windows vista and windows 2008 here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928201 but did not find anything on microsoft for windows 7.

But did not find any for windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: Be sure to back up your bitlocker keys..http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprosecurity/thread/09b6833b-e6d6-4094-a0b7-837d25063d3f

Comment: From @Moab's deleted answer: [BitLocker Drive Encryption in Win 7: FAQ](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449438(WS.10).aspx); [BitLocker Drive Encryption Ops Guide: Recovering Encrypted Volumes with AD DS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771778(WS.10).aspx); [How to use Bitlocker Data Recovery Agent](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2010/10/11/how-to-use-bitlocker-data-recovery-agent-to-unlock-bitlocker-protected-drives.aspx); [3rd party recovery software](http://www.diskinternals.com/bitlocker/); [Independent article](http://www.winvistaclub.com/f30.html)

Comment: Damn, it got the deletion hammer! Permanent solution to a temporary problem.